# Find the number of paths in random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Find the number of paths in random walk from $S_0$ to $S_{4n}$ satisfying all of the following terms:

a)$S_0 = S_{2n}=0$,

b)$S_k \ge 1 \; for \;1 \le k \le 2n-1$,

c)$S_{4n}=2$.

I need help with the above. I'm new to this subject so I'll be glad if anyone can help me with this exercise and explain this matter simply.

I know that $S_n=S_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$, where $P(X_i=1)=p$ is the probability of success, and $P(x_i=-1)=q=1-p$ is the probability of failure, and also $X_i$ are independent, but I think that I need other formulas to solve my problem.

Anyway, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something to note here is that you are counting paths so the probabilities are not actually important, especially since the $X_i$ are independent.

If we throw out condition (c) for a moment and just consider a random walk from $S_0$ to $S_{2n}$, we can actually break this problem into two halves. To satisfy condition (b) we must have $X_1 = 1$ and $X_{2n} = -1$. Between those moves we just need to make sure $S_k$ does not fall below $1$. To count this number of paths we can use the $n-2$nd Catalan number, denoted $C_{n-2}$. If you're interested in computing this thing, it has a closed form $C_n = \displaystyle\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$ and some Googling or reading on Wikipedia can lead you to a proof of that.

So we have $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n-1}\binom{2(n-2)}{n-2}$ to make the first $2n$ moves of our random walk, and then we have to make $2n$ moves that give us a net $+2$ to our position. This means we have $2$ more successes than failures, but we know that successes and failures combined add to $2n$. So we have $n+1$ successes and $n-1$ failures. They can come in any order so the number of paths to do this is $\displaystyle\binom{2n}{n+1}$.

These 'halves' were independent of each other because the $X_i$ are independent, so our total number of paths is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n-1}\binom{2n-4}{n-2}\binom{2n}{n+1}$ which maybe gets a little nicer if you expand out the binomial coefficients, though I haven't tried.

Comment: According $(a)$ and $(b)$: We also know that $S_2=2$, because we move only one up or one down, but we can't move down here. Also $S_{2n-2}=2$. So shouldn't we count the number of paths between these moves, using Catalan number? And shouldn't it be $C_{2n-5}$ then?

Comment: No, Catalan numbers will count paths that start and end at $0$ without ever going below $0$. In our case, we start and end at $1$ on $S_1$ and $S_{2n-1}$ and never want to go below $1$.

Comment: Oh, I missed the fact that Catalan numbers only count paths without going below $0$. Anyway I don't understand why we compute $C_{n-2}$ rather than $C_{2n-2}$ (or $C_{2n-3}$ because we start counting from $0$?). Also is there any equivalent formula for when paths never going over $0$? For example when $S_0=0, S_{4n}=0$ and $S_k \le 0$ for $k \in [0,2n]$? How do we calculate paths then?